# What does the "tst" instruction mean if only one operand is supplied?

Tags: assembly

I am currently very new to Assembly language, I am doing the microcorruption CTF.

The Assembly language is 32 bit.

The code follows:

```
4484 <check_password>
4484:  6e4f           mov.b @r15, r14
4486:  1f53           inc   r15
4488:  1c53           inc   r12
448a:  0e93           tst   r14
448c:  fb23           jnz   $-0x8 <check_password+0x0>
448e:  3c90 0900      cmp   #0x9, r12
4492:  0224           jz    $+0x6 <check_password+0x14>
4494:  0f43           clr   r15
4496:  3041           ret
4498:  1f43           mov   #0x1, r15
449a:  3041           ret
```

---

The function works properly, and I understand that the flag set by the result of "tst r14" must be 0 to break out of the loop.

However I am struggling to understand what operation is being preformed on the r14 to determine the value of the flag.

Normally the "tst" instruction refers to an AND operation on two operands. But with one operand i am at a stump.

Is this a difference in the archetecture the CTF is written on, or am i missing anything.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Is this AVR architecture? AVR has a `tst` instruction which tests a register with itself.

Comment: It sets one of the Z, C, O flags that `jz` and friends conditionally branch on. "Normally the "tst" instruction refers to an AND operation on two operands": really?

Comment: I had a good look, and it does not specify, other CTF levels use a von-Neumann architecture. It would make sense that it uses a register.

Comment: Sorry @user207421, I'm new to the assembly, could you elaborate more. I was under the understanding that the "tst" instruction tests the bits of the supplied operands

Comment: This one tests the bits of the supplied *operand* and sets other bits in the status word that the `jz` &c instructions work from.

Comment: What architecture are you programming for?  Looks a bit like MSP430?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Did some digging, and the "tst" instruction with one operand defaults to the second operand being also the first operand. However, I do not know the extent that this explanation covers

So, the operation would have been something like:

```
01001010
01001010
--------
01001010
```

In conclusion the <check_password> function, was reading bytes until a NULL byte was found, setting the zeroFlag to 0, than checking if the amount of bytes read equals #0x09.

So all in all, to break the function, you would need to supply 9 characters or 9 bytes.